# Shallow fetch and shallow clone

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

So, Git plugin in Jenkins offers an option to do Shallow clone.

But not shallow fetch. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the log of a job configured with a shallow clone: if the workspace is already cloned (shallow), the subsequent execution of that same job would perform a shallow fetch anyway.

Even a simple [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) would not fetch past the limit imposed by the original shallow clone. (unless you are using explicitly `--depth=`, or `--deepen=`, or `--unshallow`).
That would explain why Jenkins does not offer a shallow fetch: it is not needed when said fetch is performed inside a shallow cloned repo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems we cannot explicitly set --depth=1 during git fetch if I am already doing a shallow clone. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason indeed. It is best if the clone is already shallow with a depth set to 1.